# Can bots simulate all mouse actions?

Tags: security, web, mouse, bots

How easy is it for bots to simulate various mouse actions (click, hover, move)? If it's hard, I'm wondering why this isn't the basis of more human detection tests (as opposed to Captcha). If it's easy, then nevermind..

Comment: Very easy: http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy. For example, in Windows you could use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/):

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting.